# «Этот мир как дитя нам послушен». Почему нет запятых?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как, авторская-пунктуация

*Мы жрецы и волхвы, этот мир **как дитя** нам послушен,

И мы  сами рисуем   реальность   из звездной  пыли,

Лишь бы в нужный момент обернулись на свет наши души,

Лишь бы краски на холст, как задумано нами, легли.*
Варвара Кузьмина

"Как дитя" — не в запятых! Это правильно? Или это авторское решение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Это и правильно, и авторское решение.** В данном случае оборот может обособляться или не обособляться в зависимости от того, что в него вкладывает автор: отождествление или уподобление.

*...этот мир, как дитя, нам послушен...*: здесь говорится, что дитя послушно — и мир тоже послушен. Уподобление.

*...этот мир как дитя нам послушен...*: здесь говорится, что мир послушен именно таким же образом, каким послушно дитя. Отождествление.

Розенталь поясняет разницу:

> *Я относился к нему как к брату* — ‘он мне брат’.
> *Я относился к нему, как к брату* — ‘по-братски’, ‘он мне не брат’;
>
> *Он работал как батрак* — ‘в качестве батрака’, ‘батраком’.
> *Он работал, как батрак* — ‘много’, ‘подобно батраку’.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133718/discussion-on-answer-by-nektoid---------).

Comment: В общем, там точно не отождествление, потому что при нём подходит "в качестве", либо "считая", либо творительный падеж (тогда одно является другим). Здесь ничего из этого не подходит. А "по-детски" — это про обстоятельство образа действия. Выходит, вы понимаете эту тему, но чуть неверно.

Comment: @oleedd хорошо, я разберусь получше. Спасибо.

Comment: И ещё один момент. *"Он работал как батрак" означает "он работал по-батрачьи" или "он работал батраком"* — если есть такая двусмысленность, первый смысл закладывать нельзя, ведь воспримется в первую очередь второй. И кстати, первый вариант используется в художественных целях, а не повсеместно.

Comment: С запятыми не получается, потому что тогда: *мир нам послушен, как дитя нам послушно*. Что за дитя, которое послушно "нам" (другое дело, если дети)? Тогда надо переставить: *этот мир нам, как дитя, послушен*.

Comment: @oleedd да всё получается. В чём проблема дитяти, которое нам (к примеру, мне и супруге) послушно?

Comment: Но там ведь обращение ко всем читающим, то есть "нам всем".

Comment: @oleedd в чём проблема дитяти, которое нам всем послушно? С точки зрения русского языка — ни в чём, проблема разве что в педагогике.

Comment: @oleedd и ещё: речь там не о том, кому "нам" послушно дитя; там сравнение вообще с детским, то есть свойственным детям, послушанием. Сравните с другой пунктуацией, если бы "нам" входило в сравнительный оборот: *этот мир, как дитя нам, послушен*: дитя нам послушно, и мир нам послушен так же. Совсем другой смысл. Но запятые в таком случае должны были бы стоять

Comment: В том, что так нельзя обобщать. Нельзя сказать, что ребёнок нам всем послушен, потому что он послушен не всем, а как максимум тем, кто его окружает. Надо переставить, чтобы это "нам" не входило в сравнение. Или же "как дети нам послушны".

Comment: @oleedd в случае без запятых "нам" и не входит в сравнение, потому что в случае без запятых сравнение должно полностью заменяться наречием или творительным падежом существительного. "Как дитя" = "по-детски". Этот мир нам по-детски нам послушен. Без запятых правильным будет только такой смысл.

Comment: Ничего вам не говорил про случай без запятых. Там проблем не вижу. Как раз и должно быть без запятых.

Comment: @oleedd с запятыми тоже проблем нет. Этот мир, как дитя, нам послушен = дитя послушно (вообще послушно, а не кому-то конкретному), и мир тоже послушен.

Comment: Ну такой смысл получается. Добавьте И, чтобы уловить: *Этот мир, как и дитя, нам послушен.*

Comment: @oleedd если вы не уловили, то это не означает, что и другие не уловили. Вы допускаете ту же ошибку, которую часто допускает Jim Korbett — считаете свой нынешний уровень эталоном, выше которого никого нет. То есть если вам что-то непонятно, то и другим, мол, непонятно. Но это же не так.

Comment: Да мне понятно, это вы не можете уловить.

Comment: @oleedd тем не менее я уловил разницу безо всякой дополнительной "и".

Comment: Вы не улавливаете вот что: *Этот мир нам послушен, как и дитя нам послушно.*

Comment: Ударения должны быть такими: *Этот мИр, как дитЯ, нам послУшен.* Попробуйте так прочитать.

Comment: @oleedd да нет здесь ни в случае с запятыми, ни в случае без запятых двойного "нам". Вы его сами выдумали. *Этот мир нам послушен, как дитя (вообще, сущностно) послушно* — вот это будет расшифровка записи с запятыми.

Comment: "Нам" подразумевается в обороте из-за грамматики. Оно же прямо возле оборота стоит.

Comment: @oleedd мало ли что с чем рядом стоит. Оно *не* подразумевается. Я объяснял же: в случае без запятых оно не входит в оборот, поскольку не может войти в изменение оборота (наречие или тв. п.); в случае с запятыми оно отсечено запятой: не "этот мир, как дитя нам, послушен", а "этот мир, как дитя, нам послушен".

Comment: Когда без запятых, то да, тогда обстоятельство образа действия. А когда с запятыми, нет. Это синтаксис. "Нам" относится к "послушен", а сравнительный оборот не может прыгать через местоимение. Получается так: *этот мир, как [и] дитя, {нам послушен}*.

Comment: В данном случае "как дитя" выступает детерминантом для "нам послушен". Оно относится ко всей фразе, а не лишь к "послушен".

Comment: Сделаем зеркальную инверсию: *Послушен нам, как дитя.* Смысл при этом не меняется.

Comment: @oleedd так и что с того-то? Это мир нам послушен. Всё. Это мысль. Как дитя — это просто сравнение, придающее мысли образность, объём (в случае с запятыми).

Comment: @oleedd я понял, о чём вы говорите. Мир послушен нам, как дитя послушно нам. Но это неверная трактовка, она не следует из правила применения оборота. Мир послушен нам, как дитя послушно вообще. Только такой смысл может быть. "Нам" не двоится.

Comment: Из-за того, что "нам" сразу за оборотом, оно как бы копируется в оборот. Я улавливаю это на слух (неподходящий смысл). Для этого надо правильно прочитать (с тремя ударениями). Надо переставить оборот, чтоб исправить проблему: *этот мир нам, как дитя, послушен*. Следовательно, вариант с запятыми не подходит.

Comment: @oleedd "как бы копируется" — это ваше личное восприятие, точнее, его неверная настройка. Если бы это было всеобщим явлением, непременно бы упоминалось в каком-либо справочнике по стилистике.

Comment: А при И вы улавливаете этот неподходящий смысл? *Этот мир, как и дитя, нам послушен.* Здесь он гораздо чётче.

Comment: @oleedd я вообще не улавливаю неподходящего смысла, я просто понимаю, в чём ошибка вашей настройки восприятия — в совершенно никак не оправданном удвоении "нам".

Comment: Нет у меня ошибки восприятия. Это вы не слышите. Помню, как вы говорили про свою интонационную глухоту. Здесь оно уж точно есть. Другой пример: *Мир, как и конструктор, для нас сложен.* Такая же структура. Конструктор тоже для них сложен, а не сложен в принципе.

Comment: @oleedd с добавлением "и" — да. Без добавления "и" — нет.

Comment: Ну да, с И этот смысл усиливается, как и в примере из вопроса.

Comment: @oleedd он не усиливается, он меняется. "Мир, как конструктор, для нас сложен" = конструктор в принципе сложная штука, поэтому мир, то есть тоже сложная штука, с ним сравнивается. "Мир, как и конструктор, для нас сложен" = конкретно для них конструктор штука сложная, вот они и сравнивают мир, который для них тоже сложен, с конструктором.

Comment: А вот прочитайте с тремя логическими ударениями (как должно быть): *Этот мИр, как констрУктор, для нас слОжен. Этот мИр, как дитЯ, нам послУшен.* Это не нормальный русский язык.

Comment: @oleedd это и есть нормальный русский язык. Сложный и многообразный и многогранный. Тем более учитывая, что в поэзии он вообще часто иначе работает.

Comment: Нет, это позиция для обстоятельства образа действия (тогда одно ударение). Здесь сравнение вообще по стилистике не подходит, коверканная речь просто. Нормальна также позиция для оборота с включением. Но никак не для сравнительного. В этой теме пунктуация во многом зависит от структуры, иногда она просто исключает варианты.

Comment: @oleedd щас бы инверсию называть коверканьем. Что касается логического ударения, то оно диктуется пунктуацией. Пунктуация и расположение слов и есть способ автора показать без выделения, где расположены логические ударения. В любом случае: пруфы в студию. Я больше не стану отвечать на ваши комментарии на эту тему, если они не будут подкреплены чем-то, кроме вашего восприятия.

Comment: Здесь не инверсия, а крайне неудачная позиция для сравнительного оборота. Sharon говорит, что для обстоятельства образа действия нужно подобрать особую структуру. Так вот эта структура обычно не подходит для сравнительного оборота.

Comment: Позиция сравнительного оборота не может быть любой. Она может быть удачной (естественной), а может быть крайне неудачной (неправильный порядок слов, стилистическая ошибка). Надеюсь, хоть с этим вы согласитесь.

Comment: @oleedd единственное место, куда в данном случае не может встать сравнительный оборот, — это между 'этот' и 'мир'. Все остальные места допустимы. Как дитя, этот мир нам послушен. Этот мир, как дитя, нам послушен. Этот мир нам, как дитя, послушен. Этот мир нам послушен, как дитя. [Продолжение сообщения ниже.]

Comment: @oleedd [продолжение сообщения] У Розенталя есть рекомендации по расположению обстоятельств (http://www.rosental-book.ru/styli_xlii.html#sect181), но и там про сравнительные обороты ни слова. У Голуб в её замечательном учебнике стилистики сказано в главе про порядок слов и про детерминанты, и про обстоятельства, но ни слова про сравнительный оборот:  https://books.petr-panda.ru/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/golub_i_b_stilistika_russkogo_yazyka.pdf (страница 353 книги). Так что мой запрос пруфов актуален.

Comment: Мои дорогие друзья, я с трудом понимаю, о чем вы говорите. Поэтому решила дать свой ответ-пояснение.

Comment: @Nektoid У вас не сравнительный оборот, а вставка получается. У сравнительного оборота должна быть нормальная позиция. А то крайне неудачная позиция сопоставима со стилистической ошибкой. Между вставочной интонацией и интонацией сравнения есть разница.

Comment: @oleedd сравнительный оборот может быть одновременно и вставкой, в чём проблема? А что касается неудачных позиций — либо пруфы, либо сойдёмся на том, что это вкусовщина. Тем более что в литературе можно найти всякие варианты.

Comment: Раз вставка, ставьте два тире. Так найдите такие примеры. Так никто не напишет. Это просто ужасно.

Comment: @oleedd примеры какие? Расположение сравнительного оборота в разных местах предложения? Ну так Нацкорпус вам в помощь. *"Я, как черт, оттеле вылез!"* /  *"Они, как дети, были, военные из СССР"*...

Comment: Примеры такие: подлежащее + сравнительный оборот + местоимение + прилагательное. Могут быть дополнительные слова. Говорю именно о такой структуре, не о разных местах в предложении.

Comment: @oleedd приведите пруфы, что такая структура недопустима или хотя бы стилистически некорректна. Вы пытаетесь перевалить бремя доказательства на меня, понимая, что такой запрос нельзя толком задать в Нацкорпусе. // Впрочем, вот вам из поэтического корпуса — имеется всё запрошенное вами в указанном же вами порядке + разрешённые "дополнительные слова": *"Любуюсь **я, как властелин, её волшебною** красою!"*

Comment: Буду думать, как доказать. Также попробую точнее определить, в чём проблема. Это нормальный пример, он звучит, там есть глагол. У нас так: *что-то, как что-то другое, [для кого-то / кому-то] такое-то*.

Comment: @oleedd я всё-таки полагаю, что проблема только у вас в голове. В реальности её не вижу. Сравнительный оборот можно пхать почти куда угодно, если только автор сочтёт нужным. "А на мосту, как черт, черный взметнулся плащ" — тут вот вообще сравнение "как чёрт" выдернуто из фразеологизма "чёрный как чёрт" и переставлено волей Цветаевой в другое место.

Comment: Стоп. Проблема в "нам", оно даже без И переходит. Если его убрать, то порядок. Покажите мне хоть один пример, где следующее слово нельзя добавлять в оборот, как здесь. Похоже на нарушение грамматики. Сравниваем не со всем, а лишь со словом из фразы. Попробуем так: *Мир, как конструктор, для всех слабаков сложен.* Всё нормально? Конструктор просто сложен?

Comment: @oleedd я уже неоднократно говорил, что 'нам' никуда не переходит. 'Мир, как конструктор, для всех слабаков сложен' = конструктор вообще сложен. 'Мир, как конструктор, нам сложен' = конструктор вообще сложен. И-ден-тич-но.

Comment: Давайте у других спросим. Здесь вы точно не правы.

Comment: @oleedd развлекайтесь, кто ж вам запретит.

Comment: *Смузи, как мороженое, особенно аппетитное для тех, кому жарко.* Вы ещё скажите, что там мороженое просто аппетитное. Нет, зависимые слова и обороты тоже участвуют в сравнении.

Comment: @oleedd вы всерьёз не видите разницу между 'Мир, как конструктор, для всех слабаков сложен' и 'Мир, как конструктор, для всех слабаков сложный'? Второй вариант имеет ту же схему, что пример с мороженым, и разумеется, что во втором варианте "сложный" — это зависимое слово от "конструктор", а не от "мир". В вашем случае "аппетитное" также относится относится не к смузи, а к мороженому (потому что смузи — мужского рода, аппетитный, а не аппетитное).

Comment: У меня в примере "смузи" среднего рода, просто условно. Или замените другим словом. Что мир сложный, что конструктор. Где зависимость?

Comment: Такой пример: *Гитара, как скрипка, для маленьких детей сложна.* Скажете, что скрипка просто сложна? Но смысл не в этом.

Comment: @oleedd "мир — как конструктор: для всех слабаков сложен". Вот в таком варианте утверждается, что и мир, и конструктор сложны именно для слабаков.

Comment: Оно и в обычном утверждается. Что насчёт скрипки?

Comment: *Атом, как молекулу, под микроскопом плохо видно.* Молекулу просто плохо видно?

Comment: *Рубли, как доллары, нам нужны.* Рубли им нужны, а доллары не им нужны, а просто нужны?

Comment: @oleedd "Безумие — это точное повторение одного и того же действия. Раз за разом, в надежде на изменение" (приписывается А. Эйнштейну).

Comment: Сдавайтесь уже. Зависимые слова входят в сравнение. Через них нельзя прыгать.

Comment: @oleedd вы так и не поняли ничего... Ни то, что послушность есть сущностное свойство дитяти, а нужность не есть сущностное свойство доллара... Ни то, что если из предложения, в котором изначально было "и",  изъять "и", то это предложение не станет подобным тому, в котором "и" не было изначально... Ни то, что зависимые слова, ясно, входят в сравнение — но только те, которые зависят от того, с чем сравнивают, а не от того, чт*о* сравнивают.. Перечитайте ещё раз наш диалог, ещё раз, ещё много-много раз, и может быть, вы всё это поймёте. Засим позвольте мне уже откланяться, ибо скука смертная.

Comment: Зависимые слова всегда входят в сравнение по грамматике. Иногда это не очевидно. Вы уже делаете шаги назад к первому примеру. Ну хоть отступаете.

Comment: @oleedd я вернулся к началу, потому что вы уже сами забыли, ради чего начали этот спор.

Comment: *что зависимые слова, ясно, входят в сравнение — но только те, которые зависят от того, с чем сравнивают, а не от того, что сравнивают* — ну тогда структурная нестыковка, вы ведь её не слышите.

Comment: @oleedd я уже объяснял разницу, как я её вижу, между 'Мир, как конструктор, для всех слабаков сложен' и 'Мир, как конструктор, для всех слабаков сложный.

Comment: Демонстрирую вам эту структурную нестыковку: *Атом, как песчинку, под микроскопом плохо видно.* Песчинку просто плохо видно, под микроскопом, ясное дело, её хорошо видно. Пример корректен? Вот такая ситуация в примере из вопроса при обособлении. Просто гораздо менее очевидная.

Comment: @oleedd, вы всё ещё не поняли, что я спорил только ради того, чтобы до вас дошла проблема вашего восприятия, а не затем, чтобы просто настоять на своём? Если вы не хотите заниматься корректировкой своего восприятия — пожалуйста: я неправ, я признаю всё, что вы там захотите, только не надо делать из меня попугая, повторяющего по сотому кругу одни и те же аргументы. Да-да, вы победили, можете отметить коньячком. Разумеется, в своём творчестве я буду использовать сравнительные обороты так, как считаю нужным, пользуясь всей гибкостью русского языка; ну да вам что за дело.

Comment: Какая проблема восприятия? Там есть проблемы со структурой. Когда слышишь, что что-то не то, на самом деле что-то не то. Дыма без огня не бывает. Это не то, когда просто не нравится. "Детерминантность" при сравнении тоже действует. Какие аргументы? У вас не было ни примеров (таких же), ни каких либо аргументов. Говорю как есть. Про изъятие И согласен, то была уловка, вы не клюнули.

Comment: @oleedd подумайте над тем, что если я заметил разницу между предложениями с изъятым "и" и предложением с "как дитя", то она, разница, таки есть. Попробуйте её найти. Раз уж дыма без огня не бывает. Разглядите разницу между "рубли, как (и) доллары, нам нужны" (у долларов нет сущностного свойства 'нужности', они нужны именно им, персонажам) и "рубли, как вода, нам нужны" ('нужность' — сущностное свойство воды, она нужна вообще, нужна всем, не только персонажам). (продолжение далее)

Comment: @oleedd (продолжение) подобным образом и дитя — оно обладает послушностью вообще. "Этот мир, как Бобик, нам послушен" — вот тут бы да, "нам" играло бы роль в сравнении, потому что Бобик послушен персонажам, но нет у него такой сущностной характеристики: послушность. Вот теперь это всё обдумайте. Сколько я талдычил про сущностные свойства? — а вы не удосужились даже разузнать подробнее. Просто, очевидно, сочли априори чем-то бессмвсленным.

Comment: Ну понятно теперь. Стилистика. Надо прыгать через "нам". Так не следует делать. Здесь можно понять, что вода тоже нужна им. Потом ещё подумаю. Надо придумать похожие примеры, где будет большая структурная нестыковка.

Comment: @oleedd не стилистика это, а смысловое наполнение слов. Семантика.

Comment: Порядок слов по части стилистики.

Comment: Вы не талдычили, а раз сказали невнятно)

Comment: @oleedd я неоднократно говорил, что порядок роли не играет. Я объяснил, почему в сравнении "этот мир, как дитя, нам послушен" "нам" не входит в сравнение. В примере с Бобиком сравнительный оборот может также располагаться где угодно, но "нам", даже оторванное от него, всё равно будет его смысловой частью. Как Бобик, этот мир нам послушен. Этот мир нам послушен, как Бобик. Этот мир нам, как Бобик, послушен. Этот мир нам послушен, как Бобик дяде Серёже. Этот мир нам послушен, как дитя (которое послушно вообще).

Comment: Сравнительный оборот не должен стоять рядом с тем словом, к которому он не относится. Это мешает верному восприятию, иногда создаётся двусмысленность, иногда не звучит, порой сильная нестыковка, как в моём примере про микроскоп. Про Бобика не надо, там нет нестыковок (но там образно). В примере про воду тоже нет, но там двусмысленность (уже ошибка). А в примере из вопроса и в моём про микроскоп они есть. Так что стилистическая ошибка прежде всего в двусмысленности. И один некорректный пример уже доказывает, что сама структура некорректна. Просто порой не так критично её использовать.

Comment: @oleedd хорошо-хорошо. Я ведь уже признал вас правым во всём.

Comment: Мне нужна искренность)

Answer (score 1):

1. Мы – это **обобщенное человечество**. Из виртуальной реальности, окружающей нас, мы сами строим свою жизнь, но делаем это пока неосознанно. Мы еще не поняли всех своих возможностей, а они  действительно безграничны.
2. Итак, здесь говорится о том, что мир послушен нам **в такой же мере**, как самые маленькие дети послушны взрослым и доверяют им во всем, поэтому **он по-детски послушен, во всем послушен.**

Чтобы выразить это, я выделяю «как дитя» **логическим ударением.** Сделать это можно только при отсутствии обособления.

Это стихотворная строка с заданным порядком слов, в которой всего три слова. В конце фразы делается естественное понижение голоса,  и только  **средняя позиция** подходит для постановки  логического ударения: ***Этот мир как дитЯ нам послушен.***

3. Рассмотрим вариант  с обособлением: ***Этот мир,  как дитя,  нам послУшен***.

У обособленного сравнительного оборота вставочная интонация, он выглядит как **попутное сравнение.** Основная мысль такова: **этот мир нам послушен**.

А сравнение можно выбрать любое:  дети слушаются родителей, ученики слушаются учителя. Но это послушание  может быть разным, и подросший  ребенок уже имеет свои мнения и свои желания, это уже **не та мера послушности и полного доверия**.

Поэтому из двух возможных вариантов оформления я выбрала вариант **с логическим ударением и отсутствием обособления.**

Comment: Вы не сказали про жрецов и волхвов. Вот именно, вставочная, тогда не сравнение, а какая-то вставка получается. И ударения такие: *Этот мИр, как дитЯ, нам послУшен.* Запятые вызывают логическое ударение на предыдущем слове (здесь).

Comment: Помогите с грамматикой. Вот пример: *Мир, как конструктор, для всех слабаков сложен.* Здесь конструктор тоже сложен для слабаков, или нет?

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов может быть много. Я бы выбрал такой:

***Мы жрецы и волхвы. Этот мир – как дитЯ нам послушен…***