# Какие есть причины не обособлять сравнительный оборот, помимо тех, что указаны в этом вопросе?

Tags: untagged

Для начала я уточню, что я не считаю обороты со значением ‟в качестве” сравнительными — обороты, как в предложениях: ‟Я пришёл как врач”, ‟Как психолог, он прекрасно всё понимал”, ‟Мы знаем Индию как страну древнейшей культуры”. Я не спрашиваю о таких предложениях. Также я не считаю сравнительными обороты с ‟как и”, потому что, на мой взгляд, это присоединительный союз, как ‟да и”. Вот примеры: ‟Он не хотел это делать, как и не мог”, ‟В её глазах, как и во всём лице, было что-то необычное”.

**Какие есть причины не обособлять сравнительный оборот, помимо следующих четырёх пунктов:**

**1. Сравнительный оборот — сказуемое:**

> Как ребёнок душою я стал (Т.).
> «Город как город», — хладнокровно заметил Базаров (Т.).
> Отец и мать ей как чужие (Добр.).

**2. Сравнительный оборот — устойчивое сочетание:**

> Олени отбежали немного и остановились как вкопанные (Арс.).
> У Льва как гору с плеч свалило (Кр.).
> Разбойник мужика как липку обобрал (Кр.).
> Дождь лил как из ведра (С.‑Щ.).

**3. Сравнительный оборот предшествует некоторым частицам, как ‟не”, ‟точь-в-точь”, ‟почти”, ‟именно” и др:**

> Я воспитал в себе это чувство праздника не как отдыха и просто средства для дальнейшей борьбы, а как желанной цели (Пришв.).
> Дети иногда рассуждают совсем как взрослые.
> Было светло почти как днём; Волосы у девочки вьются точь-в-точь как у матери.
> Андрей Белый отдавался языку именно как шаман, отдающийся самовозбуждению (Фед.).

**4. Перед первой частью двойного союза, как ‟как ..., так”, ‟так ..., как”, ‟таков ..., как” и др.**

> Нигде при взаимной встрече не раскланиваются так благородно и непринуждённо, как на Невском проспекте.
> Лаевский безусловно вреден и так же опасен для общества, как холерная микроба.
> Всё вокруг какое-то церковное, и маслом пахнет так же крепко, как в церкви.

**Пара слов о сравнении характеристики действия:**
Я не вижу здесь какого-то отчетливого смысла, потому что любое сравнение, которое относится к глаголу, как-то характеризует действие. Если взять предложение: ‟Он двигал лапами, как гепард”, то  здесь сравнение используется исключительно для того, чтобы охарактеризовать действие, а не создать некое впечатление, эмоцию, отношение; но ведь даже сравнение, создающее впечатление, эмоцию, отношение, также как-то характеризует действие. Если взять любое предложение из справочника Розенталя с сравнительным оборотом с запятой, то оно определенно как-то характеризует действие:

> Иной раз подстрелишь зайца, ранишь его в ногу, а он кричит, словно ребёнок. (Разве это сравнение не характеризует действие?)
> И падшими вся степь покрылась, как роем чёрной саранчи. (Да, такое сравнение в большей мере фигуральное, чем буквально, но всё же оно характеризует действие.)
> Она глядела на него, как на икону, со страхом и раскаянием. (Разве это сравнение не характеризует действие?)

В общем, я не вижу здесь какого-то отчётливого смысла, — может быть, вы мне его сообщите.

Comment: Могу дать подсказку, но догадайтесь сами. Розенталь: Сравнительный оборот с союзом *как* не выделяется запятыми, если **на первый план** выступает значение обстоятельства образа действия.

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы там было всё детально расписано на множестве примеров. Вы же не станете отрицать, что там написана какая-то шиза. Но за эту строчку спасибо, это лучше, чем ничего.

Comment: Шиза там не написано точно, но ключевое умолчали. А формулировки да, порой ни о чём не говорят (но это не значит, что они шиза). Проблема в том, что, чем сложнее правило, тем меньше примеров. И это не вина Розенталя. Просто сложного избегают и оно в принципе редко встречается.

Comment: Никто на планете не может нормально воспринять эту писанину, это ль не показать худшего в истории учебника. Вот где у этого примера информативный характер, а не аффективный:  Как зарницы в небе они запылали, как огненный дождь с неба упали.

Comment: Воспринять можно, только не терминами же объяснять, как порой там делается. Мне лично примеры всё объясняли, а сами правила как-то читал вскользь.

Comment: Ничего там не могут объяснить примеры, примеры там такая же срань. Например, такое предложение: ‟Как град посыпалась картечь” считается характеристикой действия, такое: ‟…И падшими вся степь покрылась, как роем чёрной саранчи” — уже не характеристикой действия. Оба эти примера — аффективные сравнение, то есть те, где на переднем планет не характеристика действия.

Comment: Где сказано про передний план, там оно точно на переднем плане. Исходите из этого. Скажите мне вот что. Есть пример: *Мир, как конструктор, для всех слабаков сложен.* Здесь конструктор тоже сложен для слабаков, либо он просто сложен? Как оно воспринимается? У меня спор с кое-кем (в другом вопросе).

Comment: Видно, что вы на ходу придумали этот предложение, так как конструктор рассчитан на детей и обычно не сложен. Из-за такого характера, где предложение придумывается сходу, сложно вообще понять смысл, независимо от пунктуации. Если ‟как конструктор” обособляется, то это не сказуемое, а значит, ‟как конструктор” относится к ‟сложен”.

Comment: Кстати, в том предложении — ‟Мир, как дитя, нам послушен” — сравнительный оборот отнсоится к прилагательному, а в таких ситуациях (не уверен на все 100) всегда он обособляется. Всегда обособляется, если относится к существительному или прилагательному, кроме редких случаев. Послушен — прилагательное.

Comment: Там тоже образ действия и первый план. Конструктор может быть и не детским. Идея в том, что в мире всё состоит из деталей, как и в конструкторе. Давайте придумаем пример получше. Меня интересует в первую очередь не грамматика, а какой смысл воспринимается.

Comment: Конструктор просто — это игрушка для детей.

Comment: Представьте конструктор на 1000 деталей.

Comment: А как бы вы расставили знаки в таком предложении: ‟Её уста как роза рдеют ”? И в таком: ‟Каждое его слово как огонь обжигает”.

Comment: Запятые не нужны. Здесь первый план. Давайте придумаем пример получше (чем с конструктором).

Comment: Нет, нужны. Это примеры из справочника. Её уста, как роза, рдеют (П.)

Comment: В любом случае можно без запятых. 100%-ная гарантия. Вы пример придумывать будете по схеме моего?

Comment: Это примеры из справочника, и там они с запятыми. Не, я спать.

Comment: И что? В этих можно и без запятых. Во времена Пушкина пунктуация была другой.

Comment: Мой пример оказался даже философским. Причём его можно по-разному интерпретировать (как закон). Но почему-то заложенный смысл никто не понял. А он молодёжный. Пришлось его раскрыть.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что любое обстоятельство (обособленное или необособленное), отнесенное к глаголу,  характеризует действие.

Для примера я рассмотрю только один вопрос: ***Иной раз подстрЕлишь зайца, рАнишь его в ногу, а он кричИт, словно ребёнок.*** (Разве это сравнение не характеризует действие?)

Конечно, характеризует. Давайте для примера рассмотрим такое предложение: ***У гепарда особенный крик, его ни с кем не путаешь:  кричит как ребЁнок.***

Сочетания одинаковые, а смысл разный. Во втором случае говорится о **качественной (тембровой) характеристике** крика гепарда; это необособленное  обстоятельство, на него падает ударение.

В первом же случае  автор говорит **об эмоциях обиженного ребенка,** который не понимает, почему с ним так поступили. Ударение падает на глагол, он в центре внимания: кричит так, как кричал бы ребенок.

Чтобы расставить знаки именно так, автор **должен подобрать нужную структуру** предложения, тогда читатель прочитает и поймет текст, как нужно.

Comment: Присоединяйтесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/470077 Речь была о том, что значит "жрецы и волхвы". Что оно значит?

Comment: Непременно, но чуть позже.  Буду только вечером или завтра.

Comment: Да там коротко. Просто скажите, кого поддерживаете и почему. Да и про эту фразу. Но похоже, что Nektoid уже сдался. Говорю ему, что с запятыми не получается.

Comment: oleedd, ну я тоже думала об обособлении и сделала свой выбор.  Поэтому непременно поддержу вас...

Comment: Это знаю, но доказываю ему, что с запятыми получается бредовый смысл, и поэтому это не подходит. То есть мысль в том, что с запятыми нельзя.

Comment: Если обособить и прочитать с тремя ударениями, то у меня воспринимается как оборот со значением включения (*как и дитя*), в связи с чем "нам" дублируется (*этот мир нам послушен, как и дитя нам послушно*). А для сравнительного оборота позиция вообще не подходит, оно не воспринимается, так никто не напишет, стилистическая ошибка ("коверканная речь", как сказал Jim Korbett). А вот так нормально: *Этот мир нам, как дитя, послушен.*

Comment: У меня такая идея: для обстоятельства образа действия нужна особая структура, и эта структура не подходит для сравнительного оборота. Как-то оно обратно пропорционально получается.

Comment: @Sharon Вот примеры с ударением на обороте, который обособляется: Остап выносил терзания и пытки, как исполин. (Я. Гоголь). И грусть на дне старинной раны зашевелилася, как змей (Л.). Низко подвешенные лампочки светились, как в тумане. Загадочное слово поразило ее, как игла. (Ю. Трифонов). Её уста, как роза, рдеют (П.). На холмах паслись коровами сандагоуские избы, и церковный крест блестел на солнце, как игла. [А. А. Фадеев. Разлив (1923)]